# Calculate Exponential Moving Average

Tags: python

data is list containing candlestick objects. The c-property is the closing price of that candlestick.

I have the following Python code to calculate the EMA:

```
# Calculate to Simple Moving Average.
def sma(close_prices):
    return sum(close_prices) / len(close_prices)

# Calculate Exponential Moving Average.
def ema(close_prices):
    alpha = 2 / (len(close_prices) + 1)
    ema = sma(close_prices)
    for p in close_prices:
        ema = (p * alpha) + (ema * (1 - alpha))

    return ema

def func(data):
 
    window = 100

    if len(data) <= window:
        return 0
  
    # Extract last window-amount of elements from list except last one
    # and put the close_prices in separate list.
    close_prices = [d.c for d in data[-window:-1]]
    last_close_price = data[-1].c
 
    last_ema = ema(close_prices)
 
    if last_close_price > last_ema:
        return 0.0005   # buy
    if last_close_price < last_ema:
        return -0.0001  # sell
  
    return 0
```

First I define a window, this is the amount of candlesticks I am including in the calculation starting from the latest.

Then I put all the closing prices in a separate list `close_prices`. Note that I do this for all data points except the very last data point. The closing price of the very last data point we save in `last_close_price`.

In the function `ema()` I first calculate the SMA of all the closing_prices. This is also set as the initial value of `ema`. Then I loop over all the closing prices. The value of `ema` is updated each time with a new value. Note that in the calculation we pass the previous value of `ema` in the calculation.

On the internet they describe to use the EMA of yesterday in the calculation. I just use the EMA of the previous price.

This results in a final EMA value being returned.

I compare that last EMA value with the latest closing price we received from the stream `last_close_price` to decide the order signal (buy or sell).

Is this a valid way to calculate the Exponential Moving Average?